# GETTING ERROR : Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` supplied to `Form`, expected a ReactNode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-final-form

I am making a simple demo of `useContext` using `final-form`.I am getting this warning

**`Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop`children`supplied to`Form`, expected a ReactNode.`**

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/github/test-gitt

step to reproduce my issue or warning

1. run the application .A button is displayed . Click on button.it shows another page having a button.
2. click again the button with console open `contrl+alt+I`.

you will this warning why ?

```
<BrowserRouter>
        <LoadingProvider>
            <Router/>
        </LoadingProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

[image]

any update ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I was able to test using your provided code, this is what took that error away:

On the following line of code inside src > add-agency > index.js:54

You have to wrap the children of SForm into a Fragment in order for the children to be only one ReactNode. Something like:

```html
<SForm>
    <Fragment>
        <Tag />
        <Tag />
        <Tag />
    </Fragment>
</SForm>
```

Please consider not posting your entire code base and just write down a simple and reproducible example that can easily show what issue you're trying to figure out.

Comment: the warning does not go

Comment: please remove this answer

Comment: Did you wrap the entire content of SForm into a Fragment? I just tried again on your provided code and the error is not showing: http://prntscr.com/ot4y0d